# How to get accurate clusters using k-means clustering in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, k-means

I am doing a project on plant disease detection. I need to extract diseased parts from images of leafs but I'm not able to separate out diseased regions accurately using k-means. Specifically, the rest of the leaf is visible on the image with the diseased parts segmented. Here is the original image and image after extracting diseased parts:[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCWA9.jpg)  [image after separating diseased parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79edL.jpg)

Here is the code I have written

```
b=imread('12.jpeg');
G=fspecial('gaussian',[200 250],1);
Ig=imfilter(b,G,'same');
figure,imshow(Ig);
conversionform = makecform('srgb2lab');
lab_img = applycform(Ig,conversionform);
figure,imshow(lab_img);
ab = double(lab_img(:,:,2:3));
nrows = size(ab,1);
ncols = size(ab,2);
ab = reshape(ab,nrows*ncols,2);
nColors = 2;
[cluster_idx, cluster_center] = kmeans(ab,nColors,'distance','sqEuclidean',    ...,
                                  'Replicates',3);
pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
figure, imshow(pixel_labels,[]), title('image labeled by cluster index');
segmented_images = cell(1,3);
rgb_label = repmat(pixel_labels,[1 1 3]);
for k = 1:nColors
    color = lab_img;
    color(rgb_label ~= k) = 0;
    segmented_images{k} = color;
end
figure, imshow(segmented_images{1}), title('objects in cluster 1');
figure, imshow(segmented_images{2}), title('objects in cluster 2');
e=segmented_images{1};
figure,imshow(e);
conversionform = makecform('lab2srgb');
new_image=applycform(e,conversionform);
figure,imshow(new_image);
```

I want to extract only the diseased regions using K means clustering. I would be grateful if someone could help me with this. I am using matlab 2009a.

Comment: Why choose a size `[200 250]` for the initial filter with unit sigma? Do you know about `imgaussfilt`? Why segment with only two colors? Do you know that your code does not contain a single comment? Could you please post the original image alone so we can reproduce your results?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn I have posted the original image alone.

Comment: Mark the post below as the answer if that answers your question.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn thanks a lot for the help

Comment: No problem, please do mark the answer below if you can, just so other people can find this if they have a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a corrected code that will do what you expect:

```
function segmented_img = leaf_segmentation( original_img, nclusters )

    original_img = im2double(original_img);
    smoothed_img = imgaussfilt(original_img,1);

    conversionform = makecform('srgb2lab');
    lab_img = applycform(smoothed_img,conversionform);

    ab_img = lab_img(:,:,2:3);
    [nrows,ncols,~] = size(ab_img);
    ab_img = reshape(ab_img,nrows*ncols,2);

    cluster_idx = kmeans(ab_img,nclusters,'distance','sqEuclidean','Replicates',3);
    cluster_img = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);

    %figure, imagesc(cluster_img), title('Clustering results');

    segmented_img = cell(1,nclusters);
    for k = 1:nclusters
        segmented_img{k} = bsxfun( @times, original_img, cluster_img == k );
    end

end
```

You can call it and visualise the results like so:

```
segmented = leaf_segmentation( original, 3 );

figure;
subplot(1,3,1), imshow(segmented{1}), title('Cluster 1');
subplot(1,3,2), imshow(segmented{2}), title('Cluster 2');
subplot(1,3,3), imshow(segmented{3}), title('Cluster 3');
```

[image: Segmented leaf]

Note that the order of the clusters may vary. You can order them a posteriori knowing that the leaf should be mostly green/yellow, and that the background should be mostly black.

Comment: Could u also give me the code to order the clusters a posteriori knowing that the leaf should be mostly green/yellow, and that the background should be mostly black? I tried but wasn't able to do. Could you please help? @Sh3ljohn

Comment: @Kashish The leaf will be the image which maximises the green channel (so `argmax(cellfun( @(img) sum(sum(img(:,:,2))), segmented ))`), the background will be the one that minimises all channels (so `argmin(cellfun( @(img) sum(img(:)), segmented ))`).